# Setting environment variables for Jenkins slaves

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-agent

New to jenkins and looking to create a job. I need to use the IP of my Jenkins Instance in part of my Java Code. Is there an existing environment variable that I can use or do I have to add one myself? If so, how exactly can I do this? The slaves are ec2 instances. I looked at some similar questions posted here but it seems they are talking about the master rather than the slaves. Thanks!

EDIT: To confirm, external requests will be sent to the IP that I set in my Java code

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any such environment variable in the default list of jenkins Environment variables.

One way to set IP as environment variable on a slave is:

1. Go to the slaves configuration page
2. Under "Node properties" there is a section called "Environment Variables"
3. Add a new Environment variable, e.g. IP_ADDRESS with value = the ip of that slave.

You should be able to access it from jenkins job, just like any other environment variable. e.g. in a Shell build step ${IP_ADDRESS}